# How to select a leaf from one Jtree and display its matching results in another JTree

Tags: jtree

I have two Jtree's, In First JTree I display my directory structure which contains zip files as node child and .xlsx files as leaf. I want to add a selection event on first JTree such that when I select a leaf it should show only the matching leaf string and .xlsx files in the second JTree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to display a Node in more than one tree, since the method `add(MutableTreeNode newChild)` removes the given node from it's current parent node and so from its current tree, before it adds it to the new parent and so to the new tree. Create a new node on leaf selection, give it the value of the selected leaf node `tree.getSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent()` and add it to the other tree.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tree.getSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent()